# how to check if a particular json key has a value which is same for all the keys

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, swift3

```
For example, I have a json response of array type where the second key in each array has same value. The count of the array is dynamic  but I need to check everytime, if that particular key value is same in all the arrays, i need to hide a label.

"loadable": [
      {
        "position": {
          "positionType": "XXX",
          "thirdKey": 1,
          "fourthKey": 1,
        },
      },
      {
          "position": {
          "positionType": "XXX",
          "thirdKey": 1,
          "fourthKey": 1,
        },
      },
      {
          "position": {
          "positionType": "XXX",
          "thirdKey": 1,
          "fourthKey": 1,
        },
{
        "position": {
          "positionType": "XXX",
          "thirdKey": 1,
          "fourthKey": 1,
        },
}
}
]
```

Here i want to check if all the values for the key positionType == "XXX", then i need to hide a label. Please provide the answer in swift.

Comment: "Please provide the answer in swift." What have you tried so far?

Comment: for loadable in loadables {
if loadable.position?.positionType == "XXX" {
                    footer.labelTitle.isHidden = true
                }

Comment: Now am getting 4 arrays in which all the values are XXX. But the code which I tried is set to true even if there is one XXX and any other value other than XXX

Comment: loadables is the var of Loadable class which is NSManagedObject. var loadables: [Loadable] = [] @

Comment: @vinny Show the declaration of Loadable then

Comment: public class Loadable: NSManagedObject { @NiravD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check each value is equal in array then you can make it like this.

```
let searchValue = "xxx"
if loadables.index(where: {$0.position?.positionType != searchValue}) != nil {
    //positionType for all objects are not equal to searchValue
    footer.labelTitle.isHidden = false
}
else {
    //positionType for all objects are equal to searchValue
    footer.labelTitle.isHidden = true
}
```

Comment: this is working if any of the key matches to "XXX". But I want to hide the label if all the key values are equal to "XXX". If atleast one value is non XXX, i want to show the label

Comment: @vinny Then this solution works perfectly for that condition also check that I have edited answer try once edited answer

Comment: Thanks a ton.. that fixes the issue :) @nirav D

Comment: @vinny Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 0):

This is less of a json problem but more a question of "Do all elements in my dictionary have the same value", where the elements would be the key that you are looking for.

```
func checkValues(array: Array<Element>) -> Bool {

guard let myValue = array.firstObject()?.position?.positionType else {
    return false
}

for element in array {
    if element.position.positionType != myValue {
        return false
    }
}

return true
}
```